# Python: How to access a YouTube web page?

Tags: python, browser

I am opening a YouTube web page using the 'webbrowser' module:

```
controller = webbrowser.get()
controller.open("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMwZsFKIXa8&amp;feature=fvst")
```

The video begins to play, and I would like my Python application to resume as soon as the video ends or the browser is closed.

Now, I cannot use `time.sleep` for that, because it will force me to wait until the song is over (the app will not continue if I "fast-forward" the video, or if I simply close the browser).

So I basically need to get some indication from the web page, regarding the status of the video, and another indication in case the web page is suddenly closed.

Can I use the handle I have created using `webbrowser.get`, in order to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't at all. The `webbrowser` module hands it over to a browser over which it has no control whatsoever.

You'd need to host your own browser control through something like QtWebkit in PySide or an equivalent in pygtk/wxPython. Then you could interact with it as you would own it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use webbrowser.open, do not forget to import webbrowser lib first: 
example:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/.....")
```